# Div borders not showing

Tags: html, css, border

I'm struggling to find a direct answer to my problem due to the many variations in peoples code.

I imagine my code is probably very messy as i'm trying to build a website for my partner, and quickly (i have just a few hours Dreamweaver experience and that's it)!

Anyway, i have a fixed width website where there are around 6 separate divs in a column, all contained within a webpage-sized div for my background colour.

Anyway, when i am trying to add a border to my footer, it does not display in browsers. I just wan 1px to separate the 'main' div from the footer and it won't appear. This is also the same for my navigation div.

```
      body{
               color:#00000;
               margin-left:0px;
               margin-right:0px;
               margin-top:0px;
               margin-bottom:0px;
               }


       #body{
       background-color:#000000;
       }


       #header{
               width:800px; /* The width is fixed by pixels */
               height:150px; /* The height is fixed by pixels*/
               color:#fff;
               margin-left:auto;
               margin-right:auto;
               margin-top:0px;
               margin-bottom:0px;
        }

        #navigation {
               width:798px;
               height:51px;
               margin-left:auto;
               margin-right:auto;
               margin-top:0px;
               margin-bottom:0px;
               border-style:solid; /*Selecting solid made the border appear*/
               border-left:1px;
               border-right:1px;
               border-top:0px;
               border-bottom:1px;
               border-color:#000000;    
               text-align:center;    
               background-color:ffffff;

        }

        #main {
               width:798px; /* The width is fixed by pixels */
               height:800px; /* The height is fixed by pixels*/
               color:#fff;
               background-color:#fff;
               margin-left:auto;
               margin-right:auto;
               margin-top:0px;
               margin-bottom:0px;
               border-style:solid; /*Selecting solid made the border appear*/
               border-left:1px;
               border-right:1px;
               border-top:0px;
               border-bottom:0px;
               border-color:#000000;
               text-align:center;

        }

        #footer {
                                      /*Styling for any element with the id="container" */
                      width:798px; /* The width is fixed by pixels */
                       height:100px; /* The height is fixed by pixels*/
                       color:#fff;
                        background-color:#fff;
                        margin-left: auto;
                        margin-right:auto;
                        border-style:solid;
                        border-left:1px;
                        border-right:1px;
                        border-bottom:1px;
                        border-top:1px;
                        border-color:#000000;
                        }

                        #Facebook {
                        float:right;
                        }

                        #Twitter {
                        float:right;
                        }

                        #LinkedIn {
                        float:right;
                        }




      </style>
 </head> 
 <body>
 <div id="body">
 <div id="header">
 <a href="Home.html"><img src="Images/Logo.jpg" alt="Ruth Fifer Jewellery"> </a>
 </div>

   <div id="main">
   <div id="navigation">
   <br />
 </div>
   <br />
   <br />
   <img src="Images/Home Image.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div id="footer">

     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ruth.fifer.5?fref=ts" target="_blank"> <img src="Images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" id="Facebook"/></a>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/martynjakins" target="_blank"> <img src="Images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" id="Twitter"/></a>
   <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=225071408&trk=tab_pro" target="_blank"><img src="Images/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" id="LinkedIn"/></a></div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

If anyone is able to help it would be great, as i get the feeling I'm probably using conflicting codes due to my inexperience but don't have time to learn everything right now and will instead go back at a point where i have more time to adjust things.

Thanks,

Martyn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Write `<!DOCTYPE><html><head>` tag in the beginning of the code.

2) Write `</html>` tag in the end of the code.

AND USE:

> border: 1px 0px solid #000000;

And it will solve your problem. Look at http://jsfiddle.net/p2269/1/ I wrote code as I explained and it shows borders.

Comment: Sorry but it is complete i just didn't include it as there's javascript which I couldn't get to format right on this websites code box. Therefore, i just took an excerpt from the code minus the tags that you included and a couple of bits from the html body that had Javascript in. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Thank you! Why does it work when all the border parameters are in one line but not when i define them individually?!

Comment: Not at all! I didn't know exactly why your code didn't worked, but I knew that my variant must work, so, I tried my code and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incomplete, I think...

Here you have a working example.

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
 body{
               color:#00000;
               margin-left:0px;
               margin-right:0px;
               margin-top:0px;
               margin-bottom:0px;
               }


       #body{
       background-color:green;
       }


       #header{
               width:800px; /* The width is fixed by pixels */
               height:150px; /* The height is fixed by pixels*/
               color:#fff;
               margin-left:auto;
               margin-right:auto;
               margin-top:0px;
               margin-bottom:0px;
        }

        #navigation {
               width:798px;
               height:51px;
               margin-left:auto;
               margin-right:auto;
               margin-top:0px;
               margin-bottom:0px;
               border-style:solid; /*Selecting solid made the border appear*/
               border-left:1px;
               border-right:1px;
               border-top:0px;
               border-bottom:1px;
               border-color:#000000;    
               text-align:center;    
               background-color: yellow;

        }

        #main {
               width:798px; /* The width is fixed by pixels */
               height:800px; /* The height is fixed by pixels*/
               color:#fff;
               background-color:blue;
               margin-left:auto;
               margin-right:auto;
               margin-top:0px;
               margin-bottom:0px;
               border-style:solid; /*Selecting solid made the border appear*/
               border-left:1px;
               border-right:1px;
               border-top:0px;
               border-bottom:0px;
               border-color:#000000;
               text-align:center;

        }

        #footer {
                                      /*Styling for any element with the id="container" */
                      width:798px; /* The width is fixed by pixels */
                       height:100px; /* The height is fixed by pixels*/
                       color:#fff;
                        background-color:red;
                        margin: 0 auto;
                       border-top: 3px solid white;
                        }

                        #Facebook {
                        float:right;
                        }

                        #Twitter {
                        float:right;
                        }

                        #LinkedIn {
                        float:right;
                        }




      </style>
 </head> 
 <body>
 <div id="body">

    <div id="header">&nbsp;</div>

   <div id="main">
       <div id="navigation">
        <br />
       </div>
   </div>

   <div id="footer">&nbsp;</div>

 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but it is complete i just didn't include it as there's javascript which I couldn't get to format right on this websites code box. Therefore, i just took an excerpt from the code minus the tags that you included and a couple of bits from the html body that had Javascript in. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When containing element (div with id=footer in your case) only contains floated elements (facebook, twitter and linkedin icon) some browser will treat it as if it is zero pixels tall. You should add two CSS rule in footer selector: the overflow property with its value auto, the width property with its value 100%, to show that border.