# HTML Div border not showing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a border to a div element in HTML. Below is my code.

```css
#container-border {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-border">
  ...
</div>
```

For some reason, the border doesn't show up. I had a look on a similar question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874084/div-borders-not-showing)) but I couldn't figure out why the border doesn't show up. Any suggestions please?

Note: This snippet is a part of an HTML page. Additional code could be provided upon request

Comment: try border : `border: 2px solid red`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The default value of [`border-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) is `none`. You need to set a different value for a border to appear.

```css
#container-border {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-border">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the shortcode for border, which contains color, width AND style (which you are missing right now, and whose default setting is "none"):

```
#container-border {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the rule "**border-style**" to see the border

```css
#container-border {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style:solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-border">
  ...
</div>
```